# UIView of TableView can't scroll or tap

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

What I did was when the search controller is clicked, it shows a View with a tableView in it. (like Instagram) . **It shows the tableView but it cannot interact with it.**

I was doing some research since people had come across this before here. **Here are the things I've tried**:

> - Bring subView to the front
> - have set `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` -> Have also ran on iPhone
> - Have set tableViewHeight to ScreenHeight

**But the tableView still doesn't want to scroll/click!**

Here's the relevant code that I have if it helps,
**Controller with search bar and collection views**:

```
class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

let cellId = "cellId"

let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Search"
    return sb
}()
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    tableView.isHidden = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.text = ""
    tableView.isHidden = true
}

let tableView: UIView = {
    let tv = SearchUsersTv()
    tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tv.bringSubview(toFront: tv)
    tv.clipsToBounds = false
    return tv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.register(UserProfileVideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.isHidden = true
}
```

**Here's the code for the relevant code for the tableView (SearchUsersTv):**

```
class SearchUsersTv: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let cellId = "cellId"
var tableView = UITableView()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupTv()
}

func setupTv() {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    self.addSubview(tableView)
    bringSubview(toFront: tableView)
}
```

> Problem to fix: Make tableView scroll and click

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Why are you reinitializing tableView after you set other properties? in setupTv func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems is that you are initialising your custom class in wrongly way, you need call `SearchUsersTv(frame:` instead of `SearchUsersTv()` for initialisation because all your tableView setup happen on `setupTv()` which is called in `SearchUsersTv(frame:` initialisation only

**replace your `tableView` inline creation by this**

```
let tableView: UIView = {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let tv = SearchUsersTv(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tv.bringSubview(toFront: tv)
    tv.clipsToBounds = false
    tv.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    return tv
}()
```

Comment: AH Got it working with the code above & now understand why. Thank You!